# I want to run a script using javascript how do I do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

When I click a button I want a script that I have on my computer to run. It can be a simple print "Hello World".
How do I do that ? What I have is this :
I don't have the litle idea how do this could be done please can you help?

**HTML**

```
<input class="buttonRun" type="button" value="Run" id="btnRun"/>

 function runScript() {

            }

$("#btnRun").click(function () {
                runScript();
            });
```

**Python**

```
print ("Hello World");
```

Comment: You have to put the html tag `<script>` around the Javascript. See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: You can't run like that

Comment: Ye I know that, but i dont know the next steps, like how do i run my script python, with a click of a button,
Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="buttonRun" type="button" value="Run" id="btnRun"/>
<script>
function runScript() {
  alert('Hello World!');  
}

$("#btnRun").click(function () {
  runScript();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply myxobek, I know how to do that, but the thing is, it has to run a python script.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can pass the **scriptUrl** to this function and it will load all the methods and variable that has been wriiten in the script file.

```
 loadExternalScript(scriptUrl: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const scriptElement = document.createElement('script')
          scriptElement.src = scriptUrl
          scriptElement.onload = resolve
          document.body.appendChild(scriptElement)
      });
      }
```

may this help for you:

Answer (score 0):

You may dynamically need to append the script in your tag like this

try this

```
function runScript(){
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded') {
           callback();
       }
   };
   script.onload = callback;
   script.src = 'Your scripts path ';
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```